# Is it a Three.js bug with collada loader?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, webgl, three.js

There is a three.js demo here: http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_loader_collada.html

It works perfectly, but if I want to use canvas renderer instead of webgl, it's buggy.

```
renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
```

I can't see the texture (the object is white), and the animation also doesn't works. Is it a bug in three.js, or I have to modify more in the code?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CanvasRenderer` has several limitations. See [Issue 1026](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1026).

Default skin material is an instance of `THREE.MeshLambertMaterial`, but you can do a quick overwrite with a `THREE.MeshBasicMaterial` instance with the original texture map:

```
...
    skin = collada.skins[ 0 ];

    skin.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: skin.material.map});
...
```

And AFAIK `CanvasRenderer` doesn't support morph targets (animation).